# How to Pass multiple Arguments to Foreach Function in R

Tags: r

I try to pass some arguments to a function that contains the `foreach parallel` I got an `NA` all through.

```
future::plan(future::multisession)
n_cores <- parallel::detectCores()
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(n_cores)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = n_cores)
auto_ar1 <- function(i, n, ar){
  foreach::foreach(i, .packages = c('foreach', 'forecast')) %dopar% {
    set.seed(i)
    ar1 <- arima.sim(n=n, model = list(ar=ar, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
    ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1, ic = "aicc")
    (cf <- ar2$coef)
    if (length(cf) == 0) {
      rep(NA, 2)
    }
    else if (all(grepl(c("ar1|intercept"), names(cf))) &
             substr(cf["ar1"], 1, 4) %in% "0.80") {
      c(cf, seed = I)
    }
    else {
      rep(NA, 2)
    }
  }
}
auto_ar1(i = 289800:289805, n=10, ar=0.8)

#[[1]]
#[1] NA NA

#[[2]]
#[1] NA NA

#[[3]]
#[1] NA NA

#[[4]]
#[1] NA NA

#[[5]]
#[1] NA NA

#[[6]]
#[1] NA NA
```

When I run

```
auto_ar1(i = 289805, n=10, ar=0.8)
#[[1]]
     #ar1     seed 
     #0.8 289805.0
```

I think `289805` is a subset of `289800:289805`.

I expect the foreach function to take `289800, 289801, 289802, 289803, 289804, 289805` one after the other for `i` in `set.see(i)`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to map the auto_ar1 argument ar to the arima.sim model argument ar.

```
ar1 <- arima.sim(n, model = list(ar = ar, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your observation, I then run into another problem, the result just print out my `i`s with the number of my workers. I actually want the `i` in the `set.seed(i)` to be iterated.